# ¿Desde cuándo lo 'vicioso' es deseable?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, vocabulario, significado, historia

En el Diccionario de la Real Academia de 1884 hace su aparición una nueva acepción de **vicioso**, que se añade a las ya existentes. Sin duda, y aunque en primera instancia puede costar entenderlo al decir de algo que es *vicioso*, se trata de condiciones deseables. ¿O no es lo que diríamos de lo que se considera “abundante, provisto, deleitoso”?

Sin embargo, cuando se le pregunta a un hablante de español, prácticamente ninguno tiene en cuenta esta acepción. Por eso a muchos les entra la risa fácil cuando oyen por vez primera el nombre de una población como **Villaviciosa**, y no pueden comprender que haya una explicación diferente a la que entienden  que originó su denominación.

De hecho, si tu diccionario de cabecera es sólo el *Diccionario esencial de la lengua española* (también de la Real Academia) seguirás sin entenderlo, ya que las únicas acepciones que contempla de **vicioso** son:

1. Entregado a los vicios.
2. Que tiene, padece o causa vicio, error o defecto.

La sorpresa aumenta cuando se le enumeran todas las Villaviciosa (“villa deliciosa”) del país, que no son pocas:

- Villaviciosa (Asturias)
- Villaviciosa (Ávila)
- Villaviciosa de Córdoba (Córdoba)
- Villaviciosa de la Ribera (León)
- Villaviciosa de Odón (Madrid)
- Villaviciosa de San Miguel, anteriormente denominada     Villaviciosa de Perros (León)
- Villaviciosa de Tajuña (Guadalajara)

Mi pregunta es por qué no es hasta 1884 que aparece esta acepción, que ---eso sí--- desde entonces está siempre presente en nuestro Diccionario.

Aunque hay muchos casos, veamos un par de ejemplos, que nos indican qué se entendía antiguamente por algo *vicioso*. En la General Estoria de Alfonxo I, publicada hacia 1275, podemos leer:

> tierra de Canaán, que es muy buena tierra, e muy rica e viciosa, assí que mana leche e miel.

Y para abundar, otro ejemplo más. En el *Compendio y descripción de las Indias Occidentales* (1629) de **Antonio Vázquez de Espinosa** se describe una zona en los siguientes términos:

> La ciudad de San Joan de Pasto fundó el Capitan Lorenço de Aldana el año de 1539. llamóla villa viciosa, por ser el citio donde la fundó muy ameno, y apasible de grandes pastos para ganados (...) su temple es de primauera (...). La tierra es muy abundante, varata, y regalada, cogese en ella mucho trigo, mais, y otras semillas en abundancia, assi de España como de la tierra, tiene muy buenos ingenios de açucar, todas las frutas de España, y de la tierra, con grandes crias de ganado mayor, y menor, y inumerable de serda".

A nadie se le escapa que en ambos casos se está hablando de lugares y tierras donde por sus evidentes ventajas a cualquiera le gustaría vivir. Entonces, ¿por qué la Academia espera hasta 1884 para incluir esta acepción en el Diccionario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cuestiones**:

- Mi pregunta es por qué no es hasta 1884 que aparece esta acepción
- ¿Desde cuándo lo 'vicioso' es deseable?

---

Cuando se trata de la RAE, la polémica siempre esta servida. El hecho de que la Real Academia de 1884 añada esa nueva acepción a "vicioso", después de un periodo largo ó corto, según los casos, es muy normal. Palabras que utilizamos habitualmente y que algunas llevan tiempo, entre otras déjà vu, dabuten, turismofobia, influencer, espóiler, guasapear, efecto McFly, palabras que acaban en -mente..., aún no han sido recogidas y no se sabe si alguna vez se incorporarán al cuerpo léxico, esto sin contar aquellas otras que la RAE va poco a poco retirando.

Pero precisamente en la entrada especial que se comenta "**Vicioso**", no creo que sea el caso.

Concretamente dices que "*En el Diccionario de la Real Academia de 1884 hace su aparición una nueva acepción de vicioso*" como "*abundante, provisto, deleitoso*". Sin embargo, si esto es así, la pregunta no tiene gran fundamento ni se ha tratado con meridiano rigor, ya que tal entrada y sentido de *abundancia, vigorosidad o fortaleza*...  aparece en casi todos los diccionarios anteriores a esa fecha que tu mencionas de **1884**, hasta tal punto que llega hasta el mismo Nebrija y por tanto entendiendo en esa acepción, el sentido que adquiere la voz "Vicioso", con el significado de "abundancia".

*Diccionario de la Real Academia Española **1884***

- **VICIOSO-A** (Del lat. vitiosus) adj. Que tiene ó padece vicio ó lo causa. Entregado libremente a los vicios. U.t.c.s. / Vigoroso y fuerte, especialmente para producir. **Abundante, provisto, deleitoso**. / pr. Mimado.

---

En el Novísimo Diccionario de la Lengua Castellana, tomo II, de **1867**, es decir diecisiete años anterior a esa mención de 1884 que realizas podemos encontrar la palabra Vicioso" y su definición.

- **VICIOSO**, a adj. Epíteto de lo que tiene vicio o lo causa. Vicios / Lleno de vicios / **Abundante, provisto, deleitoso**. Abundant / p. Ar. Mimada / ant. El que vive en holgura y en la abundancia. Viciat / fo. El acto ó contrato que carece de ciertos requisitos indispensables ó sustanciales. Vicios.

---

Si nos vamos más atrás, al Diccionario de autoridades de **1726-1739**, tenemos varias entradas, en una de ellas, que es la que nos interesa, encontramos expresamente, "**se toma por vigoroso y fuerte**" y después hay un poemilla que interpreta para su comprensión esta misma acepción;

- **VICIOSO**. Se toma también por **vigoroso**, y **fuerte**, especialmente para producir. Lat. Luxurians. Ferax. LAG. Diosc. lib. 3. cap. 115. La Phylitide produce seis, ò siete hojas, semejantes à aquellas de la Romaza; empero mas luengas, mas viciosas, y mui derechas, las quales por la haz son lisas. SOLIS, Poes. pl. 114.

*Si es Santa, ò no, no me meto*;

*pero al menos tierra, que*

*sabe llevar tales plantas*,

*tierra mui viciosa es*.

---

Diccionario Latino-Español de Nebrija **1494**

En el nos encontramos, en un Latín en muchos casos vulgar, las entradas;

- Vicio, Luxus-us . Luxuria et afotia (Imagino que ferax, fértil)
- Vicioso Luxuriosus a um. afotus a um
- Vicioso en comer, nepos - nepotis
- Vicioso un poco assi, nepotulus-i

---

Para comprender el sentido de todo lo que estamos desarrollando, y sin entrar en detalles más allá, hay que entender que  "**Luxus**" significa exuberante, lujo, magnificencia, dislocado, libertinaje y "Lujuria", "**Luxuria**" en Latín, es abundancia, extravagancia, exuberancia en las plantas, exceso, afán de placeres.

Cuando la palabra "Vitium-ii", defecto, imperfección, se desarrolla en Español como Vicio, utiliza el sufijo - oso/osa que también esta en "osum", "Luxuriosum", convirtiendo "Vitium" en Vitiōsus y Vitiōsum como adjetivo y pasando a "Viciosum" en la llamada "*Lengua Rústica*", transformándolo el Español en "Vicioso".

Ese tipo de sufijo "-oso",  "Vici-oso", en líneas generales significa "abundancia de ó abundancia en", en este caso de "Vitium" / Vicios, Defectos, Imperfecciones, ó en el caso de "Luxus y Luxuria" abundante en exuberancia, profusión, exceso, abundancia (redundancia), lujo, desenfreno...

Así "Vicioso", etimológicamente hablando, significaría "Abundante en exuberancia, fertilidad, fuerza, defectos, imperfecciones..." y todas aquellas otras acepciones que lo han ido conformando.

Por tanto, y sin equivocarnos, podemos decir que esa acepción de "abundancia, fertilidad", como algo deseable, siempre ha estado presente en la palabra "Vicioso/a". Espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: No conocía estas obras de las que hablas, así que desde ahora las tendré en cuenta.